# c++: GTEST_LOG_() failed to compile

Tags: c++, debugging, logging, compilation, googletest

I've got this code snippet trying to use gtest Debug log:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int DieInDebugElse1(int* sideeffect) {
    if (sideeffect) *sideeffect = 1;
#ifndef NDEBUG
    GTEST_LOG_(FATAL)<<"debug death inside DieInDebugElse12()";
#endif  // NDEBUG
    return 12;
}
TEST(a,c){
    int sideeffect = 0;
    EXPECT_DEBUG_DEATH(DieInDebugElse1(&sideeffect), "death");
}
```

Compile error shows:

```
error: ‘FATAL’ was not declared in this scope
    GTEST_LOG(FATAL, "debug death inside DieInDebugElse12()");
            ^~~~~
m.cpp:57:15: note: suggested alternative: ‘FAIL’
    GTEST_LOG(FATAL, "debug death inside DieInDebugElse12()");
            ^~~~~
            FAIL
m.cpp:57:5: error: ‘GTEST_LOG’ was not declared in this scope
    GTEST_LOG(FATAL, "debug death inside DieInDebugElse12()");
    ^~~~~~~~~
m.cpp:57:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘GTEST_LOG_’
    GTEST_LOG(FATAL, "debug death inside DieInDebugElse12()");
    ^~~~~~~~~
    GTEST_LOG_
scons: *** [m.o] Error 1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Is that all the code? If not, is FATAL being declared anywhere? Perhaps on an include file that is not referenced?

Comment: Is `GTEST_LOG_` defined anywhere?

Comment: `m.cpp:57:5: error: ‘GTEST_LOG’ was not declared in this scope`. You have made a typo. The snippet you have posted calls `GTEST_LOG_`
The code you have compiled, but have not shown us, calls `GTEST_LOG`. `GTEST_LOG_` is defined in `<gtest/internal/gtest-port.h>`.
`GTEST_LOG` is not defined in any gtest header.

Comment: Thanks, adding this head file works!

Comment: @Troskyvs You don't need to add that header because it is already included by <gtest/gtest.h>. You just need to fix the typo.